# What is the open file in linux.?

Tags: linux

Recently we had some issue in one of our application hosted on Apache and Tomcat, were both servers have different number of open file (1024 and 5000) and that's what we thought was causing the issue. 
Verified the number open files with `ulimit -a` command.

Can some one please tell me what is this open file numbers exactly.?

Answer (score 0):

From [getrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html)

> **RLIMIT_NOFILE**
>
> Specifies a value one greater than the maximum file descriptor number that can be opened by this process.  Attempts (open(2), pipe(2), dup(2), etc.)   to
>                 exceed this limit yield the error EMFILE.

Comment: Sorry i`m not clear on the above. Is that your`re stating that the number of files opened..?

Comment: When you call `ulimit -a`, it calls `getrlimit()`. Line with `open files` shows `RLIMIT_NOFILE` limit which is shown above.